# How do I paste data into new worksheets, and delete certain rows based on cell from another table?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in an Excel spreadsheet called "Master" of about 1,000 rows I am trying to split into 42 different spreadsheets based on an identifier called the Region ID.  I have created a table with the 42 unique different regions in another spreadsheet in the same workbook, along with what I want to name the new worksheets.  I have the following code so far, which creates the 42 new spreadsheets and names them accordingly.

```
Sub Create_Tabs()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("TabList").Range("D2")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    'I would like to create code here to paste the "Master" spreadsheet contents in the newly created worksheet and keep only rows corresponding Region IDs (delete the rest).
Next MyCell
End Sub
```

How do I paste the "Master" spreadsheet contents in the newly created worksheet and keep only rows corresponding Region IDs (delete the rest)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your master data on tab names and copy them over to the new sheet.

Something like this will work. You might need to change your filter field based on your data.

```
Sub Create_Tabs_And_Copy_Data()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("TabList").Range("D2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
        'I would like to create code here to paste the "Master" spreadsheet contents in the newly created worksheet and keep only rows corresponding Region IDs (delete the rest).
         With Sheets("Master").UsedRange
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=MyCell.Value
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets(MyCell.Value).Cells(1, 1)
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    Next MyCell
    End Sub
```